# SQL Server: Filtered Index => do rows already need to exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a filtered unique index on 2 columns, on 1 condition (fkId is not null)

```
create unique index IX_Event_tbl_sourceObjectId_fkId on
 Event_tbl(sourceObjectId, fkId) where fkId is not null;
```

I assume if there are already rows where duplicates exist, the index creation will spit out an error.

But, my question is: What if there are no rows where that condition match(fkId is not null). Will there still be an error during index creation?

FYI, I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 R2 is the version

Comment: Just like you can successfully create a non-filtered index on an empty table (no rows), you can successfully create a filtered index for which the WHERE clause disqualifies all rows. It will index *future* inserts and updates that *do* match the filter. And will enforce uniqueness among those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No error will be received. Let's test:

### Duplicates

```
USE tempdb;
-- setup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Event_tbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Event_tbl;
CREATE TABLE Event_tbl
(
  sourceObjectId INTEGER NULL,
  fkid INTEGER NULL
);

INSERT INTO Event_tbl VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Event_tbl VALUES (1, 1);

-- index creation test
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Event_tbl_sourceObjectId_fkId
        ON Event_tbl (sourceObjectId, fkid)
        WHERE fkid IS NOT NULL;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
           ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
           ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
           ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
           ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
           ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH

-- tear down
DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.Event_tbl;
```

Expected error:

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement
>   terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name
>   'dbo.Event_tbl' and the index name 'IX_Event_tbl_sourceObjectId_fkId'.
>   The duplicate key value is (1, 1). The statement has been terminated.

### No duplicates, fkid NULL

```
USE tempdb;
-- setup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.Event_tbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Event_tbl;
CREATE TABLE Event_tbl
(
  sourceObjectId INTEGER NULL,
  fkid INTEGER NULL
);

INSERT INTO Event_tbl VALUES (1, NULL);

-- index creation test
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Event_tbl_sourceObjectId_fkId
        ON Event_tbl (sourceObjectId, fkid)
        WHERE fkid IS NOT NULL;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
           ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
           ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
           ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
           ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
           ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH

-- tear down
DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.Event_tbl;
```

Index is created without error.

Answer (score 1):

No you will not get an error - it just will not index any rows until rows with a non-null `fkId` are added/updated.